# Creating React Native CLI project

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I just switched to React Native from React and followed instructions on official site for creating and initialization project. I'm not using Expo, created project with npx and typescript template. When I opened project there was ruby-version and Gemfile files inside. I cannot find any documentation on website about Gemfile and why is ruby necessary in project creation, anyone got some more info or some docs that I missed on site? Thanks.

Comment: Using react native we can do iOS development. So, for ios we need cocoapods, for using cocoapods we need ruby and this Gemfile over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simple answer is for iOS Development.

Using react native we can do iOS development. So, for ios we need cocoapods, for using cocoapods we need ruby and this Gemfile over there.

Comment: I saw some project before that didn't have ruby files in root directory so when I saw it was different, but thanks so much for info. Do you know is it safe to rename index.js and App.js into .tsx files? In React when you create project with typescript template those file are automatically typescript, but in native those were created as js. Do you know the reason?

Comment: yes, It is safe @Freezy